# OpenGL: Assimp mesh incorrect

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I'm currently trying to import a Mesh using Assimp. For some reason, it's displayed incorrectly. I'm trying to load Suzanne:

[image: Suzanne Open3D]

This is a screenshot from Open3D Model Viewer - which also uses Assimp. That means the model file is correct. Now when I try to load it, it looks like this (rendered in Wireframe):

[image: Suzanne me]

I've been trying lots of things which is why I reduced the code to the minimum (no normals, texcoords, etc.) and why I'm not using any of the classes I have (except for the Shader classes, which are extensively tested and fine):

```
auto pScene = importer.ReadFile("../assets/models/suzanne/suzanne.obj",
    aiProcess_Triangulate |
    aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
    aiProcess_SortByPType
);
//aiProcess_GenNormals);

// Meshes
for (size_t stMeshIndex = 0; stMeshIndex < pScene->mNumMeshes; stMeshIndex++)
{
    auto pMeshData = pScene->mMeshes[stMeshIndex];

    // Vertices
    std::vector<float> vertices;

    for (size_t stIndex = 0; stIndex < pMeshData->mNumVertices; stIndex ++)
    {
        vertices.push_back(pMeshData->mVertices[stIndex].x);
        vertices.push_back(pMeshData->mVertices[stIndex].y);
        vertices.push_back(pMeshData->mVertices[stIndex].z);
    }

    // Indices
    std::vector<uint32_t> indices;
    for (size_t stIndex = 0; stIndex < pMeshData->mNumFaces; stIndex++)
    {
        indices.push_back(pMeshData->mFaces[stIndex].mIndices[0]);
        indices.push_back(pMeshData->mFaces[stIndex].mIndices[1]);
        indices.push_back(pMeshData->mFaces[stIndex].mIndices[2]);
    }

    GLuint gl_vao;
    GLuint gl_vbo;
    GLuint gl_ibo;

    // Vertex Array
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &gl_vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &gl_vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &gl_ibo);

    // Shader
    auto pVertexShader = pRenderer->CreateShader(ShaderType::Vertex);
    if (!pVertexShader->CompileFromFile("shader/default_simple.vs"))
        return;

    auto pFragmentShader = pRenderer->CreateShader(ShaderType::Fragment);
    if (!pFragmentShader->CompileFromFile("shader/default.fs"))
        return;

    auto pShaderProgram = pRenderer->CreateShaderProgram();
    pShaderProgram->AttachShader(pVertexShader);
    pShaderProgram->AttachShader(pFragmentShader);
    if (!pShaderProgram->Link())
        return;

    glm::vec2 viewportSize = { 800,600 };// pRenderer->GetContext()->GetViewportSize();
    auto matProjection = glm::perspective(
        glm::radians(45.0f),
        viewportSize.x / viewportSize.y,
        0.1f,
        1000.0f);

    auto matView = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(3, 3, 0),
        glm::vec3(),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

    auto matModel = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    auto matMVP = matProjection * matView * matModel;
    pShaderProgram->Use();
    pShaderProgram->GetUniform(ShaderUniformRole::TransformMVP)->SetValue(matMVP);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * pMeshData->mNumVertices, &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uint32_t) * pMeshData->mNumFaces * 3, &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(gl_vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)0);

    while (!pRenderer->GetContext()->GetWindow()->ShouldClose())
    {
        glClearColor(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        pShaderProgram->Use();

        glBindVertexArray(gl_vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_vbo);

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); // Wireframe

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_ibo);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, pMeshData->mNumFaces * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        pRenderer->GetContext()->GetWindow()->SwapBuffers();
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

The shaders are minimalized too:

```
#version 410
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vp;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main() {
  gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vp, 1.0);
}

#version 410
out vec4 color;

void main()
{    
    color = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

This is Assimp's log output:

[image: Assimp Log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't test it. But I'm assuming it's because of this:

```
glBufferData(... sizeof(float) * pMeshData->mNumVertices ...);
```

You're forgetting to multiply `mNumVertices` by `3`:

```
glBufferData(... sizeof(float) * pMeshData->mNumVertices * 3 ...);
```

Since you already have `vertices`, you could also do:

```
glBufferData(... sizeof(float) * vertices.size() ...);
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake. I had the misconception that mNumVertices was the total amount of points.